# Color changed Convert RGB to CMYK

Tags: coreldraw

I created a image in RGB mode in Corel Draw X6.

see the example of image and tell me the solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean that, when converting from rgb to cmyk, the color changed to a more dull hue. This is because of the conversion from a 'wide' color space to a 'narrow' color space. All colors are mapped to values within a much smaller color space. If you don't use this image for (offset)printing, you may want to keep on using rgb so there is a wider range of colors to be used.

Comment: The word "gamut" may be useful.  And it doesn't have to be wide/narrow:  So long as RGB contains even one color CMYK cannot represent, such conversions are possible, even if the opposite is also true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change Default Color Palettes go on the top of page you will see File, Edit, View...etc, choose Window, scroll down, open Color Palettes and click on CMYK, Pantone, whatever.

You can simply right click and select "View" and chose palette. It will be added to colors on the right side of screen. I use home old version of Corel, but I don't think basic rules have changed in new version.